# Scipy optimize.minimize function

Tags: python, scipy, nonlinear-optimization

I try to solve nonlinear programming task using scipy.optimize.minimize

```
max r
x1**2 + y1**2 <= (1-r)**2
(x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2 >= 4*r**2
0 <= r <= 1
```

So I've wrote next code:

```
r = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
x1 = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y1 = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
x2 = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y2 = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)


fun = lambda r: -r
cons = ({'type': 'ineq',
     'fun': lambda x1, r: [x1[0] ** 2 + x1[1] ** 2 - (1 - r) ** 2],
     'args': (r,)},
    {'type': 'ineq',
     'fun': lambda x2, r: [x2[0] ** 2 + x2[1] ** 2 - (1 - r) ** 2],
     'args': (r,)},
    {'type': 'ineq',
     'fun': lambda x1, x2, r: [(x1[0] - x2[0]) ** 2 + (x1[1] - x2[1]) ** 2 - 4 * r ** 2],
     'args': (x2, r,)})
bnds = ((0, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, 1))
x0 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
minimize(fun, x0, bounds=bnds, constraints=cons)
```

But I've got next error

```
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\slsqp.py", line 377, in _minimize_slsqp
c = concatenate((c_eq, c_ieq))
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Please, help me to find out my mistakes and write correct code

**UPD:**
Thx to @unutbu i've understand how to build it correctly.

```
fun = lambda x: -x[0]
cons = ({'type': 'ineq',
     'fun': lambda x: -x[1] ** 2 - x[2] ** 2 + (1 - x[0]) ** 2},
    {'type': 'ineq',
     'fun': lambda x: -x[3] ** 2 - x[4] ** 2 + (1 - x[0]) ** 2},
    {'type': 'ineq',
     'fun': lambda x: (x[1] - x[3]) ** 2 + (x[1] - x[4]) ** 2 - 4 * x[0] ** 2})
bnds = ((0, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, 1))
x0 = [0.5, 0.3, 0.5, 0.3, 0.5]
answer = minimize(fun, x0, bounds=bnds, constraints=cons)
```

In task of minimization we have to lead constraints to such form:

```
g(x) >= 0
```

that's why constraints look like in that way.

Comment: Could it be that the 3rd `cons` function takes 2 arguments.  Everything else is using 1, which according to `x0` is a 5 element array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parameter space appears to be 5-dimensional.  A point in your parameter
space would be `z = (r, x1, y1, x2, y2)`.  Therefore the function to be minimized
-- and also the constraint functions -- should accept a point `z` and
return a scalar value.

Thus instead of

```
fun = lambda r: -r
```

use

```
def func(z):
    r, x1, y1, x2, y2 = z
    return -r
```

and instead of

```
lambda x1, r: [x1[0] ** 2 + x1[1] ** 2 - (1 - r) ** 2]
```

use

```
def con1(z):
    r, x1, y1, x2, y2 = z
    return x1**2 + y1**2 - (1-r)**2
```

and so on.

---

Note that simple constraints such as `0 <= r <= 1` can be handled by setting the `bounds` parameter instead of defining a constraint. And if the bounds for `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2` are from -1 to 1, then you might also want change

```
x1 = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
...
```

to

```
x1 = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
...
```

However, the arrays `r`, `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2` are not needed to minimize `func`, so you could just as well eliminate them from the script entirely.

---

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as optimize

"""
max r
x1**2 + y1**2 <= (1-r)**2
(x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2 >= 4*r**2
0 <= r <= 1
"""

def func(z):
    r, x1, y1, x2, y2 = z
    return -r

def con1(z):
    r, x1, y1, x2, y2 = z
    return x1**2 + y1**2 - (1-r)**2

def con2(z):
    r, x1, y1, x2, y2 = z
    return 4*r**2 - (x1-x2)**2 - (y1-y2)**2 

cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': con1}, {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': con2},)
bnds = ((0, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, 1))
guess = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
result = optimize.minimize(func, guess, bounds=bnds, constraints=cons)
print(result)
```

yields

```
     fun: -1.0
     jac: array([-1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 14
     nit: 2
    njev: 2
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```