# scipy/optimize/slsqp.py c = concatenate((c_eq, c_ieq)) ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I am new to scipy.optimize, after looking it's tutorial and refenrence I still can't understand what I did wrong in my code.
I read this and can't understand either :[Scipy optimize.minimize function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37777025/scipy-optimize-minimize-function)

Here D is a M*N matrix, y is a M*1 matrix.  x should be a N*1 matrix(because I need to calculate that). I need to minimize the L2 norm in x, make sure every elements in x is greater than 0. Also subject to Dx=y. In conclude:

> minimize||x||2
>
> Dx=y
>
> x>=0

```
import scipy
from numpy import *

def square_sum(x):
    #x must be 1*N?
    x = x.reshape(len(x),1)
    y = dot(x.T,x)
    return y

def lessObsConstrain(x,D,y):
    #Dy=x equals (Dy-x)^2=0
    temp = y - dot(D,x.reshape(len(x),1))
    temp = temp.reshape(1,len(temp))
    return dot(temp,temp.T)

x0=ones((D.shape[1],))
result = scipy.optimize.minimize(square_sum, x0, args=(), method='SLSQP', jac=None, bounds=scipy.optimize.Bounds(0, 1), constraints=[{'type':'eq','fun':lessObsConstrain,'args':(D,y)}], tol=None, callback=None, options={'maxiter': 100, 'ftol': 1e-06, 'iprint': 1, 'disp': False, 'eps': 1.4901161193847656e-08})
```

But I get this error:

> scipy/optimize/slsqp.py", line 417, in _minimize_slsqp
>       c = concatenate((c_eq, c_ieq)) ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

Can someone tell me how to correct my code please?

Comment: Review the bounds requirements.  It looks like it's trying to join the equality and inequality parameters.

Comment: If `x0` is (N,) shape, `np.dot(x,x)` is the vector dot produce, magnitude.  No need for `x.T`.

Comment: Could you explain "join the equality and inequality parameters"? I really don't know where is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I found a ugly way to pass this error. It turns out the 1*1 matrix is different from a scalar. So the problem is data dimension.

```
import scipy
from numpy import *

def square_sum(x):
    return dot(x,x)

def lessObsConstrain(x,D,y):
    temp = y - dot(D,x.reshape(len(x),1))
    temp = temp.reshape(1,len(temp))
    return asscalar(dot(temp,temp.T))

x0=ones((D.shape[1],))
result = scipy.optimize.minimize(square_sum, x0, args=(), method='SLSQP', jac=None, bounds=scipy.optimize.Bounds(0, 1), constraints=[{'type':'eq','fun':lessObsConstrain,'args':(D,y)}], tol=None, callback=None, options={'maxiter': 100, 'ftol': 1e-06, 'iprint': 1, 'disp': False, 'eps': 1.4901161193847656e-08})
```

Comment: If you `dot` a (1,n) array with a (n,1) (its transpose), the result is a (1,1) array.  `dot` of a (n,) with itself produces a scalar.  You made that change in `square_sum`.  Do it also in `lessObsConstrain`.

Comment: I don't know how to do that because lessObsConstrain would require more reshape, make it hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [37]: from scipy import optimize
```

Dummy arrays, just for testing shapes:

```
In [39]: D = np.eye(4,3); y = np.ones((4,1))                                    
In [40]: D                                                                      
Out[40]: 
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
In [41]: y                                                                      
Out[41]: 
array([[1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.]])
In [42]: x0 = np.ones((D.shape[1],))
```

Your latest functions:

```
In [57]: def square_sum(x): 
    ...:     return np.dot(x,x) 
    ...:  
    ...: def lessObsConstrain(x,D,y): 
    ...:     temp = y - np.dot(D,x.reshape(len(x),1)) 
    ...:     temp = temp.reshape(1,len(temp)) 
    ...:     return np.asscalar(np.dot(temp,temp.T))
```

With the original versions, they both produced 2d arrays:

```
In [44]: square_sum(x0)                                                         
Out[44]: array([[3.]])
In [45]: lessObsConstrain(x0,D,y)                                                                  
Out[45]: array([[1.]])
```

and the constraint handler complained it couldn't join the equality and inequality constraints (I'm not sure exactly what it's concatenating):

```
c = concatenate((c_eq, c_ieq))

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)
```

With `asscalar` the `lessObsConstrain` is scalar, and the join works.

```
In [60]: optimize.minimize(square_sum, x0, args=(), method='SLSQP', jac=None, bo
    ...: unds=optimize.Bounds(0, 1), constraints=[{'type':'eq','fun':lessObsCons
    ...: train,'args':(D,y)}], tol=None, callback=None, options={'maxiter': 100,
    ...:  'ftol': 1e-06, 'iprint': 1, 'disp': False, 'eps': 1.4901161193847656e-
    ...: 08})                                                                   
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:7: DeprecationWarning: np.asscalar(a) is deprecated since NumPy v1.16, use a.item() instead

Out[60]: 
     fun: 2.9994000807884227
     jac: array([1.99980003, 1.99980003, 1.99980003])
 message: 'Positive directional derivative for linesearch'
    nfev: 218
     nit: 20
    njev: 16
  status: 8
 success: False
       x: array([0.99990001, 0.99990001, 0.99990001])
```

I was recommending a simple `dot` that doesn't require reshape.  But `y` also needs to 1d (like `x0`):

```
In [61]: def square_sum(x): 
    ...:     return np.dot(x,x) 
    ...:  
    ...: def lessObsConstrain(x,D,y): 
    ...:     #Dy=x equals (Dy-x)^2=0 
    ...:     temp = y - np.dot(D,x) 
    ...:     return np.dot(temp,temp) 
In [62]: y = np.ones((4))
```

The minimize call produces the same thing:

```
In [56]: optimize.minimize(square_sum, x0, args=(), method='SLSQP', jac=None, bo
    ...: unds=optimize.Bounds(0, 1), constraints=[{'type':'eq','fun':lessObsCons
    ...: train,'args':(D,y)}], tol=None, callback=None, options={'maxiter': 100,
    ...:  'ftol': 1e-06, 'iprint': 1, 'disp': False, 'eps': 1.4901161193847656e-
    ...: 08})                                                                   
Out[56]: 
     fun: 2.9994000807884227
     jac: array([1.99980003, 1.99980003, 1.99980003])
 message: 'Positive directional derivative for linesearch'
    nfev: 218
     nit: 20
    njev: 16
  status: 8
 success: False
       x: array([0.99990001, 0.99990001, 0.99990001])
```

Looking more carefully at `lessObsConstrain`.  The first dot produces a size M array ((MxN with a N):

```
In [62]: np.dot(D,x0)                                                           
Out[62]: array([1., 1., 1., 0.])
In [63]: y       # (N,1)                                                                  
Out[63]: 
array([[1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.]])
In [65]: lessObsConstrain(x0,D,y)                                               
Out[65]: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

(N,1) broadcasts with (N,) to produce (N,N).  If instead `y` is (N,), `temp` is 1d, and its `dot` is a scalar:

```
In [66]: lessObsConstrain(x0,D,np.ones((4,)))                                   
Out[66]: 1.0
```

`dot` combines the last axis of A with 2nd to the last of B.  But with 1d array it the scalar vector dot, magnitude:

```
In [67]: np.dot(np.arange(3),np.arange(3))                                      
Out[67]: 5
In [68]: np.dot(np.arange(3)[:,None],np.arange(3)[None,:])                      
Out[68]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],     # (3,1) with (1,3) => (3,3)
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 4]])
In [69]: np.dot(np.arange(3)[None,:],np.arange(3)[:,None])                      
Out[69]: array([[5]])    # (1,3) with (3,1) => (1,1)
```